# python selenium href address is too long to get the right data

Tags: python, selenium, download, href

Recently I get a strange problem to solve.
by using selenium, I know I can use

```
abc="www.cnn.com" 

browser = webdriver.Chrome() 

browser.get(abc)
```

to get the href content.

But today I get a question, my href is very long(I get it from a website). in fact, the href address in the web shows:

```
href:=data:text/csv;charset=UTF-8…20%23%2C%23Y%23%23%2C%23PA%22%0A
```

See, there is "..." in the address, if I put mouse in the address, it shows a very long content which is right, that is what I want to click to download.

But when I use `get_attribute("href")` to get the address, it only shows the short one:

```
data:text/csv;charset=UTF-8,%22lalala%22%2C%22ccccc%22%2C%22assigned_dog%22%2C%22assigned_soa_cat%22%2C%22vio_apple%22%2C%22car%22%2C%22bike%22%0A
```

so when I click and download the file, it only has the tile of the file

> lalala   ccccc   assigned_dog   assigned_soa_  cat   vio_apple   car
>   bike

So anyone has this problem? do u know how to solve it by using python and selenium?

Comment: Even if you do manually, you are getting  the same file with title alone. Right?

Comment: well, if I click it from the html source code, since the source code is the full long href, so I get the right file. 
But if I copy the href into the chrome address place, since I only copy the short one, I can only get the part file, which is only the title.

Comment: What do you get from right click + copy link address?

Comment: right click + copy link address works fine in the html code page, I can get the full path, but do u know how to do the same thing by using selenium and python? the get_attribute("href") is the only way for me right now to get the address. however, it is very short not the full one, any command for that?